# Passport google Oauth redirect to installed pwa app breaks login

Tags: javascript, reactjs, progressive-web-apps

I have created a webapp where I use passport.js google strategy everything works well. the only problem is when I set display mode to standalone in manifest and then install the PWA app next time when I try to login  using google Oauth the redirect callback link opens in pwa app and this break the login returns internal server error

How can I fix this everything works as expected in display mode browser

Answer (score 0):

I was just stuck on the same problem.

What worked for me is to change `start_url` in `manifest.json` from `/` to `/menu` (whatever you have there).Now the app is not being opened and breaking Google login.